# Find particular data and copy the contents till the row ends

Tags: vba, excel, copy, find

I have maintained two Excel reports `EPC1.xlsx` and `Control Power Transformers.xlsm` respectively.

I want to trigger an button click from `Control Power Transformers.xlsm` report where it will search for `"CTPT"` term in "A" column from `EPC1.xlsx`, once it finds the term it need to copy Column B and Column c till the row ends (in `EPC1.xlsx`) and paste it in `Control Power Transformers.xlsm` workbook

I am successful in retrieving the cell address of "CTPT" term but how to select the data from adjacent column B and C?

[image]

And this is what I have tried

```
Private Sub CommandButton23_Click()
Dim rngX As Range
Dim num As String

Windows("EPC 1.xlsx").Activate
Set rngX = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000").Find("CTPT", Lookat:=xlPart)
num = rngX.Address ' Here we will the get the cell address of CTPT ($A$14)
Range(rngX, Range("C" & rngX.Row).End(xlDown)).Copy
Windows("Control Power Transformers.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("E2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `FindNext` to find other results, and the `Offset` will help you select what you want from the address of your results :

```
Sub test_Karthik()
Dim WbEPC As Workbook, _
    WbCPT As Workbook, _
    WsEPC As Worksheet, _
    WsCPT As Worksheet, _
    FirstAddress As String, _
    WriteRow As Long, _
    cF As Range, _
    num As String

Set WbEPC = Workbooks("EPC 1.xlsx")
Set WbCPT = Workbooks("Control Power Transformers.xlsm")
Set WsEPC = WbEPC.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WsCPT = WbCPT.Sheets("Sheet2")

With WsEPC
    .Activate
    With .Range("A1:A10000")
    'First, define properly the Find method
        Set cF = .Find(What:="CTPT", _
                    After:=ActiveCell, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)

        'If there is a result, keep looking with FindNext method
        If Not cF Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = cF.Address
            Do
                num = cF.Address ' Here we will the get the cell address of CTPT ($A$14)
                WsEPC.Range(cF.Offset(0, 1), cF.Offset(0, 2).End(xlDown)).Copy
                WriteRow = WsCPT.Range("E" & WsCPT.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                WsCPT.Range("E" & WriteRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

                Set cF = .FindNext(cF)
            'Look until you find again the first result
            Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste the below in sample workbook. The below code will help to select both files using file dialog. It will search for word "CTPT". if so it will copy the column values from CTPT sheet to control file.

```
Sub DetailsFilePath()

Dim File1 As String
Dim File2 As String
Dim findtext As String
Dim copyvalues As Long
Dim c As Variant

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

MsgBox "Open the CTPT file"

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).Show


'On Error Resume Next

' open the file

File1 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).SelectedItems(1)

MsgBox "Open the Control Power Transformers file"


Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).Show

File2 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).SelectedItems(1)




Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=File1)
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("sheet1")


Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=File2)
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("sheet1")




findtext = "CTPT"

   With ws1.Columns(1)
        Set c = .Find(findtext, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                copyvalues = c.Column
            ws2.Columns(2).Value = ws1.Columns(2).Value
            ws2.Columns(3).Value = ws1.Columns(3).Value


             End If
    End With


wb1.Close savechanges:=True
wb2.Close savechanges:=True



End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @newjenn, the solution is working just as i expected!

Comment: @newjenn : Don't forget to loop with `FindNext` method to find all the results! Check my answer if you want to see how! ;)

Comment: @R3uK Thanks Buddy Sure,  i will use it